# How to build if-conditional function in StreamBuilder that filter using 2 sub function

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, if-statement, conditional-statements

Let Start! (Using Firebase to fetch data from)

I want to add an `if-conditional` in `StreamBuilder` that

> if "dropdowncompany" == "ซินเนติก" -> use OverviewPurchase() function

> if "dropdowncompany" == "ซินโนวิค" -> use OverviewPurchase1() function

I have a picture from my Firebase that shows the location of the value in the 'dropdowncompany' field. [View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmFYz.png)

and that's two function of `OverviewPurcahse()` and `OverviewPurchase1()`

**OverviewPurchase Code**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OverviewPurchase extends StatefulWidget {
  const OverviewPurchase({super.key});

  @override
  State<OverviewPurchase> createState() => _OverviewPurchaseState();
}

class _OverviewPurchaseState extends State<OverviewPurchase> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream:
              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("pr_details").snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(60.0),
              child: Container(
                width: size.width * 0.25,
                child: ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Card(
                          borderOnForeground: true,
                          color: Colors.lightBlueAccent[100],
                          child: ListTile(
                              leading: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                icon: Icon(Icons.list_alt_outlined),
                                iconSize: 30,
                              ),
                              title: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Chip(
                                    label: Text("ใบขอซื้อ Synatic"),
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              subtitle: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(document["purchase_req"]),
                                  Text("บริษัท  :  " +
                                      document["dropdowncompany"]),
                                  Text("แผนก  :  " + document["dropdowndep"]),
                                  Text("ประเภทงาน  :  " +
                                      document["dropdownwork"]),
                                  Text(
                                      "ชื่อ-นามสกุล  :  " + document["fsname"]),
                                  //Text("แผนก  :  " + document["department"]),
                                  Text(
                                      "วันที่เขียน  :  " + document["date_pr"]),
                                  Text(
                                      "จำนวนรายการ  :  ${int.parse((document['number1']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number2']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number3']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number4']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number5']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number6']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number7']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number8']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number9']).length.toString()) + (int.parse((document['number10']).length.toString()) - 1)}")
                                ],
                              ))),
                    ],
                  );
                }).toList()),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

**OverviewPurchase1 Code**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OverviewPurchase1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const OverviewPurchase1({super.key});

  @override
  State<OverviewPurchase1> createState() => _OverviewPurchase1State();
}

class _OverviewPurchase1State extends State<OverviewPurchase1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream:
              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("pr_details").snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(60.0),
              child: Container(
                width: size.width * 0.25,
                child: ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Card(
                          borderOnForeground: true,
                          color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[100],
                          child: ListTile(
                              leading: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                icon: Icon(Icons.list_alt_outlined),
                                iconSize: 30,
                              ),
                              title: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Chip(
                                    label: Text("ใบขอซื้อ Synovic"),
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              subtitle: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(document["purchase_req"]),
                                  Text("บริษัท  :  " +
                                      document["dropdowncompany"]),
                                  Text("แผนก  :  " + document["dropdowndep"]),
                                  Text("ประเภทงาน  :  " +
                                      document["dropdownwork"]),
                                  Text(
                                      "ชื่อ-นามสกุล  :  " + document["fsname"]),
                                  Text(
                                      "วันที่เขียน  :  " + document["date_pr"]),
                                  Text(
                                      "จำนวนรายการ  :  ${int.parse((document['number1']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number2']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number3']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number4']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number5']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number6']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number7']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number8']).length.toString()) + int.parse((document['number9']).length.toString()) + (int.parse((document['number10']).length.toString()) - 1)}")
                                ],
                              ))),
                    ],
                  );
                }).toList()),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

**OverviewPurchase1 Code**

So next That is what I wrote

------------------ My if conditional code--------------------------

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:inventory_app/screens/purchases/overview-purchases-syna.dart';
import 'package:inventory_app/screens/purchases/overview-purchases-syno.dart';

class Divided1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Divided1({super.key});

  @override
  State<Divided1> createState() => _Divided1State();
}

class _Divided1State extends State<Divided1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("pr_details").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final selectD1 = snapshot.data?.docs.reversed.toList();
            snapshot.data!.docs.map((docum) {
              if (selectD1 != null && docum["dropdowncompany"] == "ซินเนติก") {
                OverviewPurchase();
              } else if (selectD1 != null &&
                  docum["dropdowncompany"] == "ซินโนวิค") {
                OverviewPurchase1();
              }
            }).toList();
          }
          
        });
  }
}
```

------------------ My if conditional code--------------------------

Finally, It's the code that shows the the result that is filtered

**Output Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:inventory_app/pallete.dart';
import 'package:inventory_app/screens/purchases/overview-divided.dart';
import 'package:inventory_app/screens/purchases/po-purchases.dart';
import 'package:inventory_app/screens/purchases/pr-purchases.dart';
import 'package:inventory_app/screens/purchases/quotation-purchases.dart';
import 'package:inventory_app/screens/welcome-screens.dart';

class PipelinePurchase extends StatefulWidget {
  const PipelinePurchase({super.key});

  @override
  State<PipelinePurchase> createState() => _PipelinePurchaseState();
}

class _PipelinePurchaseState extends State<PipelinePurchase> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "Purchasing",
            style: kBodyText,
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                return CustomCarouselFB2();
              }));
            },
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back_ios,
              color: kWhite,
            ),
          ),
          bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
            Tab(
              child: Text(
                "Pipelines",
                style: kBodyText,
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Text(
                "ใบขอซื้อ",
                style: kBodyText,
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Text(
                "เปรียบเทียบใบเสนอราคา",
                style: kBodyText,
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Text(
                "ใบสั่งซื้อ",
                style: kBodyText,
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(children: [
          Divided1(),
          PrPurchase(),
          QuotationPurchase(),
          PoPurchase(),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I got "The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end." in my if-conditional build :( like this
[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ommbu.png)

As you can see the `Divided1()` in the Output code, I want to complete `Divided1()` as `If-conditional` in `StreamBuilder` that filter 2 of `OverviewPurchase()` and `OverviewPurchase1()`

Comment: `stream:
              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("pr_details").snapshots(),` Don't build the stream as the stream: parameter in StreamBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of theStreamBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Answer (score 2):

"build" has a return type of "Widget" not "Widget?". This means that you always need to return something, but in your code if "snapshot.hasData" is false you don't return anything. Try to determine what you want to return if the snapshot contains no data, maybe CircularProgressIndicator() for a loader, or SizedBox.shrink() for an empty box.

It will look like:

```dart
if(snapshot.hasData) {
  // return your Widget, which depends on your streams data
} else {
  return CircularProgressIndicator();
}
```